# SparklyR separate one Spark DataFrame column into two columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, sparklyr

I have a dataframe containing a column named **COL** which is structured in this way:

> VALUE1###VALUE2

The following code is working

```
library(sparklyr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
mParams<- collect(filter(input_DF, TYPE == ('MIN')))
mParams<- separate(mParams, COL, c('col1','col2'), '\\###', remove=FALSE)
```

If I remove the `collect`, I get this error:

```
Error in UseMethod("separate_") : 
  no applicable method for 'separate_' applied to an object of class "c('tbl_spark', 'tbl_sql', 'tbl_lazy', 'tbl')"
```

Is there any alternative to achieve what I want, but without collecting everything on my spark driver?

Answer (score 4):

You can use ft_regex_tokenizer followed by sdf_separate_column.

ft_regex_tokenizer will split a column into a vector type, based on a regex. sdf_separate_column will split this into multiple columns.

```
mydf %>% 
    ft_regex_tokenizer(input_col="mycolumn", output_col="mycolumnSplit", pattern=";") %>% 
    sdf_separate_column("mycolumnSplit", into=c("column1", "column2")
```

UPDATE: in recent versions of sparklyr, the parameters input.col and output.col have been renamed to input_col and output_col, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Sparklyr version 0.5 has just been [released](https://blog.rstudio.org/2017/01/24/sparklyr-0-5/), and it contains the `ft_regex_tokenizer()` [function](http://nl-svr-bda2:8787/help/library/sparklyr/html/ft_regex_tokenizer.html) that can do that:

> A regex based tokenizer that extracts tokens either by using the
> provided regex pattern to split the text (default) or repeatedly
> matching the regex (if gaps is false).

```
library(dplyr)
library(sparklyr)
ft_regex_tokenizer(input_DF, input_col = "COL", output_col = "ResultCols", pattern = '\\###')
```

The splitted column "ResultCols" will be a list.

Comment: I know `ft_regex_tokenizer`, but the question was to separate the values and store it in 2 columns and not in 1 list column. `tidyr::unnest` is just working locally after `collect`, which is not appropriate in my case, because I have to aggregate the data using 1 output column ...

Comment: Note: in recent versions of sparklyr, the parameters input.col and output.col have been renamed to input_col and output_col, respectively.

Comment: I would suggest editing the answer to show input_col and output_col now that this is the current implementation.