# Sparklyr: how to calculate correlation coefficient between 2 Spark tables?

Tags: r, apache-spark, dplyr, sparkr, sparklyr

I have these 2 Spark tables:

```
simx
x0: num 1.00 2.00 3.00 ...
x1: num 2.00 3.00 4.00 ...
...
x788: num 2.00 3.00 4.00 ...
```

and

```
simy
y0: num 1.00 2.00 3.00 ...
```

In both tables, each column has the same number of values. Both table `x` and `y` are saved into handle `simX_tbl` and `simY_tbl` respectively. The actual data size is quite big and may reach 40GB.

I want to calculate the correlation coefficient of each column in `simx` with `simy` (let's say like `cor(x0, y0, 'pearson')` ).

I searched everywhere and I don't think there's any ready-to-use `cor` function, so I'm thinking about using the correlation formula itself (just like [mentioned in here](http://study.com/academy/lesson/pearson-correlation-coefficient-formula-example-significance.html)).

Based on a good explanation in [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43614220/7913448), I think using `mutate_all` or `mutate_each` is not very efficient and gives a `C stack error` for a bigger data size, so I consider to use `invoke` instead to call functions from `Spark` directly.

So far I managed to get until here:

```
exprs <- as.list(paste0("sum(", colnames(simX_tbl),")"))

corr_result <- simX_tbl%>%  
  spark_dataframe() %>% 
  invoke("selectExpr", exprs) %>% 
  invoke("toDF", as.list(colnames(simX_tbl))) %>% 
  sdf_register("corr_result")
```

to calculate the `sum` of each column in `simx`. But then, I realize that I also need to calculate the `simy` table and I don't know how to interact the two tables together (like, accessing `simy` while manipulating `simx`).

Is there any way to calculate the correlation in a better way? Or maybe just how to interact with other Spark table.

My Spark version is 1.6.0

EDIT:
I tried to use `combine` function from `dplyr`:

```
xy_df <- simX_tbl %>% 
  as.data.frame %>%
  combine(as.data.frame(simY_tbl)) %>%
  # convert both table to dataframe, then combine. 
  # It will become list, so need to convert to dataframe again
  as.data.frame 

xydata <- copy_to(sc, xy_df, "xydata") #copy the dataframe into Spark table
```

But I'm not sure if this is a good solution because:

1. Need to load into dataframe inside of R, which I consider non-practical for big size data
2. When trying to `head` the handle `xydata`, the column name becomes a concat of all values

   ```
   xydata %>% head
   Source:   query [6 x 790]
   Database: spark connection master=yarn-client app=sparklyr local=FALSE
   ```

   c_1_67027262134984_2_44919662134984_1_85728542134984_1_49317262134984_ 
                                                                          
       1                                                               1.670273
       2                                                               2.449197
       3                                                               1.857285
       4                                                               1.493173
       5                                                               1.576857
       6                                                              -5.672155

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I would solve it by going back to [the input dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43589762/6910411). Just for the record the input data has been loaded using CSV reader:

```r
df <- spark_read_csv(
  sc, path = path, name = "simData", delimiter = " ", 
  header = "false", infer_schema = "false"
) %>% rename(y = `_c0`, xs = `_c1`)
```

and looks more or less like this:

```
      y                                                   xs
  <chr>                                                <chr>
1 21.66     2.643227,1.2698358,2.6338573,1.8812188,3.8708665
2 35.15 3.422151,-0.59515584,2.4994135,-0.19701914,4.0771823
3 15.22  2.8302398,1.9080592,-0.68780196,3.1878228,4.6600842
```

Now instead of splitting data into mutlitple tables let's process both part together:

```r
exprs <- lapply(
 0:(n - 1), 
 function(i) paste("CAST(xs[", i, "] AS double) AS x", i, sep=""))

df %>% 
  # Convert to native Spark
  spark_dataframe() %>%
  # Split and select xs, but retain y
  invoke("selectExpr", list("y", "split(xs, ',') AS  xs")) %>%
  invoke("selectExpr", c("CAST(y AS DOUBLE)", exprs)) %>%
  # Register table so we can access it from dplyr
  invoke("registerTempTable", "exploded_df")
```

and apply `summarize_each`:

```r
tbl(sc, "exploded_df") %>% summarize_each(funs(corr(., y)), starts_with("x"))
```

```
Source:   query [1 x 5]
Database: spark connection master=local[*] app=sparklyr local=TRUE

         x0         x1        x2         x3         x4
      <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1 0.8503358 -0.9972426 0.7242708 -0.9975092 -0.5571591
```

A quick sanity check (correlation between `y` and `x0`, `y` and `x4`):

```
cor(c(21.66, 35.15, 15.22), c(2.643227, 3.422151, 2.8302398))
```

```
[1] 0.8503358
```

```r
cor(c(21.66, 35.15, 15.22), c(3.8708665, 4.0771823, 4.6600842))
```

```
[1] -0.5571591
```

You can of course center the data first:

```
exploded <- tbl(sc, "exploded_df")

avgs <- summarize_all(exploded, funs(mean)) %>% as.data.frame()
center_exprs <- as.list(paste(colnames(exploded ),"-", avgs))

transmute_(exploded, .dots = setNames(center_exprs, colnames(exploded))) %>% 
  summarize_each(funs(corr(., y)), starts_with("x"))
```

but [it doesn't affect the result](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/16710):

```
Source:   query [1 x 5]
Database: spark connection master=local[*] app=sparklyr local=TRUE

         x0         x1        x2         x3         x4
      <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1 0.8503358 -0.9972426 0.7242708 -0.9975092 -0.5571591
```

If both the `transmute_` and `summarize_each` causes some issue we can push the centering and correlation directly into Spark:

```
#Centering
center_exprs <- as.list(paste(colnames(exploded ),"-", avgs))

exploded %>%  
  spark_dataframe() %>% 
  invoke("selectExpr", center_exprs) %>% 
  invoke("toDF", as.list(colnames(exploded))) %>%
  invoke("registerTempTable", "centered")

centered <- tbl(sc, "centered")

#Correlation
corr_exprs <- lapply(
  0:(n - 1), 
  function(i) paste("corr(y, x", i, ") AS x", i, sep=""))

centered %>% 
  spark_dataframe() %>% 
  invoke("selectExpr", corr_exprs) %>% 
  invoke("registerTempTable", "corrs")

 tbl(sc, "corrs")
```

```
Source:   query [1 x 5]
Database: spark connection master=local[*] app=sparklyr local=TRUE

         x0         x1        x2         x3         x4
      <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1 0.8503358 -0.9972426 0.7242708 -0.9975092 -0.5571591
```

Intermediate table is of course not necessary and this could be applied at the same time as we extract data from arrays.

Comment: Splendid, good Sire! The centering part will also cause `C stack error`, but we can use `invoke` to avoid this. To save you from trivial problem, I edited your answer and added the centering part so that other readers can also reference to this.