# Sparklyr: how to apply an operation between a column in Spark table and an R dataframe?

Tags: r, apache-spark, dplyr, sparkr, sparklyr

I have this Spark table:

```
xydata
y: num 11.00 22.00 33.00 ...
x0: num 1.00 2.00 3.00 ...
x1: num 2.00 3.00 4.00 ...
...
x788: num 2.00 3.00 4.00 ...
```

And this dataframe in R environment:

```
penalty
p: num 1.23 2.34 3.45 ...
```

with the number of rows in both table and dataframe are the same.

I want to subtract `y` values in `xydata` with `p` in `penalty`, something that is like `y = y - p`.

Is there any way to do this? I know I can use `mutate` to update `y`, that can only be used in the same table.

I'm thinking about combining both table into a new Spark table:

```
xydata_new
y: num 11.00 22.00 33.00 ...
x0: num 1.00 2.00 3.00 ...
x1: num 2.00 3.00 4.00 ...
...
x788: num 2.00 3.00 4.00 ...
p: num 1.23 2.34 3.45 ...
```

so that I can use `mutate(y = y - p)`, but again I cannot find a good way to combine both tables. I tried to use `dplyr::combine` in [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43632558/7913448), but the result is not satisfying.

Data size is big, it can reach 40GB and maybe even more in the future, so `collect`-ing all tables into R environment to then be manipulated within R (`cbind` then export as Spark table with `tbl`) is not an option.

Comment: Spark does not guarantuee any row order in its DataFrames at all, so i am not sure that some kind of cbind between a SparkDataFrame and a local R dataframe would yield the results you expect. Is row order important for you?

Comment: Unfortunately row order is important because each row represents one sample, so they have to be paired. Can you please explain why the row order is not guaranteed?

Comment: it's because Spark Dataframes are partitioned. It depends on how you've created both your DataFrame and your penalty whether you can assume the row order is preserved (e.g., if you've done a `sort` then your data will remain in that order). [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29268210/mind-blown-rdd-zip-method/29281548#29281548) is a hopefully helpful discussion on that topic.