# How to get probability values from Spark model predictions using sparklyr?

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

I am working with the `sparklyr` package with data in Spark. I'm building a logistic regression model and having some trouble figuring out how to get the probabilities for each class out of the probability column of the predictions data frame produced by `ml_predict()` on my model.

Here is some short sample code that demonstrates what I'm doing:

```r
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)

sc <- spark_connect(master = "local[1]", version = "2.3.2")

iris_sc <- copy_to(sc, iris)
modelPipeline <- ml_pipeline(sc) %>%
   ft_r_formula(Species ~ Sepal_Length + Sepal_Width + Petal_Length + Petal_Width) %>%
   ml_logistic_regression()

modelFit <- ml_fit(modelPipeline, iris_sc)

predictions <- ml_predict(modelFit, iris_sc)
```

<sup>Created on 2018-10-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

This produces a Spark dataframe with a column named `probability` which is 
a `org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT` datatype in Spark with three elements per row representing the model's probability predictions for each of the three possible classes.

How can I get one of these values out of this object using `sparklyr`? Something like `probability[1]` of course doesn't work in `sparklyr` and I'm not finding a function in `dplyr` or `sparklyr` which might be useful.

Comment: This link might have some useful comments. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43589762/sparklyr-how-to-explode-a-list-column-into-their-own-columns-in-spark-table